# ¿Cómo hago para que regrese a la primera pregunta?

Tags: c

Mi problema es que cuando conteste que hay cero y respondo que no, quiero que me repita la pregunta, en cambio me repite que si hay cero infinitas veces hasta que conteste que si hay cero, lo que quiero es que cuando conteste no, regrese a la primera pregunta de cuantos alumnos hay.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char letra;

int numero,contador;
char buffer[100];
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    FILE*fp;

    printf("Cuantos alumnos vinieron?");
    scanf("%d",&numero);


    if(numero==0)
    {  
        do{
            printf("¿seguro son cero?");
            scanf("%c",&letra);
        }while(letra != 's');
    }


    fp = fopen ("fichero.txt","a+t");
    for(contador=0;contador<numero;contador++)
    {
        printf("ingresa el nombre del alumno");
        scanf("%s",&buffer);
        fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
        fprintf(fp,"%s","\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si te ingresan números negativos?

Answer (score 0):

Proba con este codigo, lo que esta mal son los bucles que hiciste:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char**argv) { 

FILE*fp;
int numero=1,contador; 
char buffer[100];
char letra = 'n';

do{

printf("Cuantos alumnos vinieron?");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&numero);

if(numero==0){
    printf("Seguro que son cero?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&letra);
}
    }while(numero==0 and letra=='n');



fp=fopen ("fichero.txt","a+t");
for(contador=0;contador<numero;contador++)
{
    printf("ingresa el nombre del alumno");
    scanf("%s",&buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"%s","\n");
}

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

lo probe y cuando pongo 0 alumnos me pregunta si estoy seguro, si pongo que si el programa termina, si pongo que no me vuelve a preguntar constantemente hasta que ponga un valor distinto de 0. Si pongo algun valor distinto de 0 me pregunta el nombre del alumno y continua normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    printf("¿seguro son cero?");
    scanf("%c",&letra);
}while(letra != 's');
```

Este bucle se repite mientras `letra` no sea `'s'`. Dicho de otra manera, a no ser que respondas `'s'`, el bucle se repetirá infinitamente… que es exactamente lo que describes que está sucediendo:

> Me repite que si hay cero infinitas veces hasta que conteste que si hay cero.

El comportamiento que quieres es otro, que no se corresponde con el código publicado:

> Quiero que cuando conteste no, regrese a la primera pregunta de cuantos alumnos hay.

Si quieres ese comportamiento, tendrás que repetir la pregunta si y sólo si:

1. El número es cero.
2. La respuesta es no.

```
int continuar = 1;

while (continuar == 1)
{
    int numero;
    printf("Cuantos alumnos vinieron?");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    if (!alumnos) // El número es cero?
    {
        char letra;
        printf("¿seguro son cero?");
        scanf("%c",&letra);

        continuar = !(letra == 'n'); // La respuesta es no?
    }
}
```